# Why doesn't Google serve adsense over SSL?

Tags: apache, ssl, adsense

I was just curious as to why Google doesn't allow you to use a version of the Adsense code that is served via SSL, I was wondering if there was extra cost involved or something?

I'm just asking because I used to serve my website over SSL but it displayed a warning in Google Chrome because the ads weren't being served over SSL.

Thanks in advance,
Francis :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Enabling SSL may seem a very quick and easy fix, but SSL places a significant load on the server and each request will take slightly longer than without encryption.  On a small site with minimal traffic, you probably won't notice the extra overhead.  On a platform as big as Adsense, decisions like this require a great deal more planning; not to mention more powerful servers or load-balancing SSL appliances. I can't imagine there's enough demand for it to justify the extra costs involved.</strike>

Comment: Google admitted that SSL adds just about 4-5% to the server load, so it's not the issue.